# Instantiating Generic Types

Tags: generics, typescript, instantiation

Given the following class:

```
class Datum {}
```

I get an error message (`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'`) when I try to do the following:

```
class Data<T extends Datum> {
    datum: T

    constructor() {
        this.datum = new T()
    }
}
```

So then I try doing this, but I also get an error message (`Type 'Datum' is not assignable to type 'T'`):

```
 class Data<T extends Datum> {
    datum: T

    constructor() {
        this.datum = new Datum();
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is it not possible to instantiate the constrained type T?  My assumption was that since T is constrained such that it must extend `Datum`, I'd be able to do `datum: T = new Datum()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things to remember: First, generics are erased during compilation. They have no runtime impact, so any attempt to reference a generic type as if it were a runtime value has no meaning.

Second, it's possible for a derived class of `Datum` to have constructor parameters. Even if `T` did exist, you can't just blindly `new` it with zero arguments.

Putting that together, what you want is this:

```
class Datum {}

class Data<T extends Datum> {
    datum: T

    constructor(ctor: new() => T) {
        this.datum = new ctor();
    }
}

class ByteDatum extends Datum {
    new() { }
}

let y = new Data(ByteDatum);
let x = y.datum; // x: ByteDatum
```